# Getting records structured the same way only partially

Tags: database, database-design, logic

While surfing through 9gag.com, an idea (problem) came up to my mind. Let's say that I want to create a website where users can add diffirent kinds of entries. Now each entry is diffirent type and needs diffirent / additional columns.

Let's say that we can add:

- a youtube video
- a cite which requires the cite's author name and last name
- a flash game which requires additional game category, description, genre etc.
- an image which requires the link

Now all the above are all entries and have some columns in common (like id, add_date, adding_user_id, etc...) and some diffirent / additional (for example: only flash game needs description or only image needs plus_18 column to be specified). The question is how should I organize DB / code for controlling all of the above as entries together? I might want to order them, or search entries by add_date etc...

The ideas that came up to my mind:

1. Add a "type" column which specifies what entry it is and add all the possible columns where NULL is allowed for not related to this particular type columns. But this is mega nasty. There is no data integration.
2. Add some column with serialized data for the additional data but it makes any filtration a total hell.
3. Create a master (parent) table for an entry and separate tables for concrete entry types (their additional columns / info). But here I don't even know how I'm supposed to select data properly and is just nasty as well.

So what's the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent table seems like the best option.

```
// This is the parent table
Entry
  ID PK
  Common fields

Video
  ID PK
  EntryID FK
  Unique fields

Game
  ID PK
  EntryID FK
  Unique fields

...
```

What the queries will look like will largely depend on the type of query. To, for example, get all games ordered by a certain date, the query will look something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Game
JOIN Entry ON Game.EntryID = Entry.ID
ORDER BY Entry.AddDate
```

To get *all* content ordered by date, will be somewhat messy. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Entry
LEFT JOIN Game ON Game.EntryID = Entry.ID
LEFT JOIN Video ON Video.EntryID = Entry.ID
...
ORDER BY Entry.AddDate
```

If you want to run queries like the one above, I suggest you give unique names to your primary key fields (i.e. `VideoID` and `GameID`) so you can easily identify which type of entry you're dealing with (by checking `GameID IS NOT NULL` for example).

Or you could add a `Type` field in `Entry`.